# Как копировать файлы в gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm

Имеется вот такая файловая структура:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── scripts
│   └── styles
├── gulpfile.js
└── src
    ├── index.html
    ├── scripts
    │   └── app.js
    └── styles
        └── style.scss
```

Нужно скопировать `index.html` из `/src/` в `/dist/`. Для этого я пробовал использовать такой код:

```
gulp.task('copy'),function(){
    return gulp.src('/src/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/'))
}
```

Однако при исполнении задачи ничего не происходит.

Как мне скопировать этот файл через gulp?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция никогда не будет вызвана. Фикс:

```
gulp.task('copy', function(){
```